# Date and Time Format Conversion in Pandas, Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Initially, my dataframe had a **Month** column containing numbers representing the months.

| **Month** |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

I typed `df["Month"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Month"])` and I get this...

| **Month** |
| --- |
| 970-01-01 00:00:00.0000000001 |
| 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002 |
| 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000003 |
| 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000004 |

I would like to just retain just the dates and not the time. Any solutions?

Comment: You input datetime information seems partial and not fit to be cast into an absolute time?  Are these months from an origin?

Comment: The "Month" column has literally integers such as those above. If by **origin** you mean the original dataset, then yes.

Comment: "*I would like to just retain just the dates*" - for a date, you'll also need at least a year, and probably a day, so what do you expect those to be?

Comment: @MrFuppes I wrote this command, **pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None**) for both rows and columns. Somehow the dataset doesn't display all the rows. 
When I plot it, I see the date ranges from, **1968-1**, **1968-7**, **1969-1**, **1969-7** . . . . upto **1972-1**

Comment: I don't get it, from your example I assumed you had a column that *just has a number, which represents a month*. Can you clarify? Can make the example a working [mre]?

Comment: @MrFuppes Yes you are correct. That is precisely what I have initially when I load the dataset. Then when I performed **to_datetime()** I get whats in the tables above. 

As per your first question, Year/s = 1968 till 1972.

Comment: do you have the year specified in another column or where are those numbers coming from?

Answer (score 0):

get the date from the column using df['Month'].dt.date

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use `format='%m'` in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df["Month"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Month"], format='%m') 
print (df)
       Month
0 1900-01-01
1 1900-02-01
2 1900-03-01
3 1900-04-01
```

Comment: Tried this, it returns the same output as mine above.

Comment: @Qas - like `1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002` ? Are you sure?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that still.

Comment: @Qas - and not forget for `, format='%m'` ? If not, what is your pandas version?

Comment: Yeah I didnt forget that :D 
I wrote the exact code you mentioned above and still got the same thing.